# How can I get my icons, wallpapers and network-manager back on XUBUNTU 14.04 after accidentally upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, xfce

so I was trying to install Flask last night and I accidentally typed in
'`sudo apt-get upgrade`

I woke up this morning and all I had was gone. No seriously, everything with an icon on my desktop has an icon with a big X on it. When I try to open images, they don't. My wallpaper is blue and when I go to change it, there are literally blanks where wallpapers should be. Changing the folder to another folder doesn't work. My internet is working but the network manager is gone. My volume icon is gone but clicking it just gives me the mute option and a menu of white space. The top left menu icon is gone. A huge chunk of my icons are just not there.

I am thinking of just reinstalling ubuntu but if anyone knows the culprit, you'd save me an hour of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try reinstalling the Xubuntu Desktop metapackage and see it replaces the broken/missing files.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop